# How to draw route line between pointers

Tags: android, google-maps

I have many location pointers on my map now i want to connect all these pointers to one another through route line my map is like this screenshot see this screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPmmR.png)

above is the screenshot of my map now i want to draw lines with pointers i want to make like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvD5J.png)
my map java code is below what can i do to draw route line on map

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    http = new Http();
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("dbapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    avatarName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mProfiletv);
    profileName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mActName);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    Intent mapScreen= getIntent();
    stringID=mapScreen.getStringExtra("ID");
    Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"[MapActivity::onCreate()]UID List:"+ stringID);
    userDetail=null;
    try {
        userDetail = new JSONObject(mapScreen.getStringExtra("jsonform"));

        profileName.setText(userDetail.getString("name"));


        String test = userDetail.getString("name");
        String s=test.substring(0,1);
        avatarName.setText(s);
        avatarName.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(mapScreen.getStringExtra("color")));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"Exception:"+e.getMessage());
    }


}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String response;

            String body = "UID=" + stringID;
            response = http.postRequest(HttpConfigs.URL_COORDINATES, body);
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            try {
                final JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
                remoteMessage = responseJson.getString("message");
                if (responseJson.getBoolean("result")) {
                    JSONArray data = responseJson.getJSONArray("data");
                    Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"Map DATA"+data.toString());
                    //Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, data.toString());

                    //Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "Testing "+ data.length());
                    //Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "Testing "+ data.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        String lon = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("lon");
                        String lat = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("lat");
                        String time = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("time");

                        LatLng loc = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon));
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("Marker: "+i+" "+time));
                        if (i == data.length() - 1)
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 13));
                    }


                } else {
                    showMessage(remoteMessage);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline)

```
PolylineOptions mRacePolyLineOptions=new PolylineOptions();
mRacePolyLineOptions.width(5);
mRacePolyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);

mRacePolyLineOptions.add(new LatLng(12.222,45.222));
mRacePolyLineOptions.add(new LatLng(17.222,555.222));
Polyline mRacingPolyLine = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(mRacePolyLineOptions);
```

The LatLng values you need to populate accordingly